# Using Numpy on IronPython 64 Bit

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, ironpython, python.net

Is it possible at all to use numpy on IronPython 64-bit?  I've made an attempt to use the packages distributed by Enthought but they do not work.

Any suggestions on this?  Are there any projects currently working on getting numpy to work with 64-bit IronPython?

Comment: What is the exact problem, what have you tried?

Comment: Any luck ? This is driving me nuts...

Comment: have you tried pythonnet?